# unable to access index for repository http://cran.irsn.fr/bin/windows/contrib/2.6

Tags: r

When I try to download package on R 2.6.0. I get the following message:

```
Avis : unable to access index for repository http://cran.irsn.fr/bin/windows/contrib/2.6
Avis : unable to access index for repository http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/2.6
Erreur dans install.packages(NULL, .libPaths()[1], dependencies = NA, type = type) : 
  no packages were specified
```

Have anyone any idea about how to fix this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`R 2.6.0` is 9 years old. Which is ancient. Binary packages for version that old are no longer provided. `R 2.11.0` is the oldest version with binaries for Windows.

The easy solution: upgrade to the latest version `R 3.3.0`

Harder solution: install the packages from source if you must use `R 2.6.0`. All package sources are available on CRAN.